# iphone sdk 3.2 to 4.0 nib editing

Tags: iphone, sdk, nib

So I am working on an app that was compiled on sdk 3.2 and 2.2.1, but I have sdk 4.0. When I compile it, I get many build errors "Pattern colors not supported by the iphone SDK for iphone OS versions prior to 3.0" and "setText is deprecated."

Furthermore, when I open a nib file and try to change the colors, add in an item from the library, or mess around with it my changes and additions don't show up during runtime. I am thinking this is an issue with the interface builder, particularly the different SDK versions.

Is this the case? I am programming for the ipad, so I need at least 3.2?

Answer (score 4):

Open the .xib file in Interface Builder, then select `Window` > `Document Info`, select a later version of `Deployment Target` OS version.

Comment: I was getting the "Pattern colors are not supported..." error, and this solution fixes the problem.  Turns out some of our really old views were still configured for iOS2

Answer (score 1):

Your errors of "setText is deprecated" is an error in your code because apple updated their framework. The easiest to fix that would be to check the framework for a comment that says what to use.

When you make a change to a nib file, interface builder and Xcode require that you save before building the project.

The iPad is only 3.2, so yes you will need to build it for iOS 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am OP, had to create an account since I was using a temp one.

Thanks for the answer, however, I'm not too worried about setText is deprecated because it builds successfully.

Regarding the nib file, I did save, clean and rebuild the project. I'm working on someone else's code done in earilier sdk's, and when I delete their objects in IB the app will still run fine, as though the interface builder is not responding. I add objects in the nib and they won't show up. If I do this is projects I create, it goes through finely. My guess is it's the different sdks?